# SPFX - Why it creates files when I enter the command "gulp serve" in Visual Studio Code

Tags: json, typescript, sharepoint, gulp, spfx

When I start my local server with the command "gulp serve", instead of displaying my first web part in the browser, it creates files.

[Here is the command line image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QjOOu.png)

I have checked my gulpfile.js and package.json, there's no problem with them.

gulpfile.js:

```
'use strict';

const build = require('@microsoft/sp-build-web');

build.addSuppression(`Warning - [sass] The local CSS class 'ms-Grid' is not camelCase and will not be type-safe.`);

var getTasks = build.rig.getTasks;
build.rig.getTasks = function () {
  var result = getTasks.call(build.rig);

  result.set('serve', result.get('serve-deprecated'));

  return result;
};

build.initialize(require('gulp'));
```

package.json:

```
  "name": "jquery-project",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=16.13.0 <17.0.0"
  },
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "gulp bundle",
    "clean": "gulp clean",
    "test": "gulp test"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "tslib": "2.3.1",
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "17.0.1",
    "office-ui-fabric-react": "^7.199.1",
    "@fluentui/react": "^7.199.1",
    "@microsoft/sp-core-library": "1.17.4",
    "@microsoft/sp-component-base": "1.17.4",
    "@microsoft/sp-property-pane": "1.17.4",
    "@microsoft/sp-webpart-base": "1.17.4",
    "@microsoft/sp-lodash-subset": "1.17.4",
    "@microsoft/sp-office-ui-fabric-core": "1.17.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@microsoft/rush-stack-compiler-4.5": "0.5.0",
    "@rushstack/eslint-config": "2.5.1",
    "@microsoft/eslint-plugin-spfx": "1.17.4",
    "@microsoft/eslint-config-spfx": "1.17.4",
    "@microsoft/sp-build-web": "1.17.4",
    "@types/webpack-env": "~1.15.2",
    "ajv": "^6.12.5",
    "eslint": "8.7.0",
    "gulp": "4.0.2",
    "typescript": "4.5.5",
    "@types/react": "17.0.45",
    "@types/react-dom": "17.0.17",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "4.3.0",
    "@microsoft/sp-module-interfaces": "1.17.4"
  }
}
```

Comment: don't post pictures of text, post text

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.